# Sqlparameters - pass them to a method

Tags: c#, sql, methods, parameters

I have a method like this one:

```
private void SetDataSet(string sqlString, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))     
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.
                cmd.CommandText = sqlString;

                if (parameters != null)
                {
                    foreach (SqlParameter parm in parameters)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
                    }
                }

                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                     cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Now, from the other method called testMethod, I'd like to call "SetDataSet" with all needed arguments. Unfortunately I don't know how to "construct" the needed sqlparameters and how, later, pass them info "SetDataSet" method.

```
private void testMethod()
{
  string sqlString = .... .

  //here should be the code, which will create sql parameters

  //and now we call the SetDataSet with all needed arguments:
  SetDataSet(sqlString, ?!);
}
```

I was thinking about some kind of loop, which could create sqlparameters array(?) in testMethod, and then pass it to the SetDataSet method, however dont know how to accomply that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems that you need to study about collections and arrays.

Comment: Where does your parameters come from?

Comment: If you are generating the query in the `testMethod`, why don't you embed the parameters in the string at once?

Comment: You don't need the `SqlDataAdapter` in your method, the `DataSet` is also redundant. The check if the newly created  connection is closed is also pointless. Instead of passing the sql string and the parameters to the method i would suggest to create menaingful methods like `InsertProduct`(with appropriate strong typed properties) or whatever since that is less error-prone and more reusable.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is provide the parameters. The `params` parameter will automatically create the array.

```
 SetDataSet(sqlString, param1, param2, param3, ..., paramN);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create SQL parameters?

Like this:

```
SqlParameter SqlParm = new SqlParameter("ID", SqlDbType.Int);
SqlParm.Value = 100;
```

If you think you are making some kind of generic way to do all your database stuff, you will end up creating a new layer but not avoiding the nuts and bolts of accessing a database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create SQL parameters?

Like this:

```
SqlParameter sqlP1= new SqlParameter("Id", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlP1.Value = 200;
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
private void testMethod() 
{
    string sqlString = .....

    //here should be the code, which will create sql parameters

    // An varchar(80) parameter called @Name with the value "Chuck".
    SqlParameter paramName = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 80);
    paramName.Value = "Chuck";

    // An int parameter called @Age with the value 49.
    SqlParameter paramAge = new SqlParameter("@Age", SqlDbType.Int);
    paramAge.Value = 49;

    // Create more parameters here, as many as you want.
    // You could also create a SqlParameter[] array and send in instead.

    //and now we call the SetDataSet with all needed arguments:
    SetDataSet(sqlString, paramName, paramAge); // just add all parameters one after another.
}
```

Since you are using a `params` parameter in `SetDataSet(string sqlString, params SqlParameter[] parameters)` you can add zero or how many parameters you want after the `sqlString` parameter.